# How to open or download an excel file with Knime from SharePoint?

Tags: excel, database, sharepoint, knime

I have a corporate SharePoint platform of course and I want to:

-Open or download-to-soon-modify some Excel files
-Download and upload files after some changes

Or, is there a way for getting Knime to retrieve data from SAP GUI?

But I don´t get how to, seems to be Knime can not open an Excel file or csv online.

Any suggestion? Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

In general, the [Excel Reader (XLS)](https://nodepit.com/node/org.knime.ext.poi2.node.read3.XLSReaderNodeFactory) node will allow you to read files from a URL. You can e.g. simply enter an `http:` or `https:` URL instead of a local file path, and in case the web server does not require any authentication, the node will download and parse the file.

Speaking of SharePoint however, the files you need to access are likely protected by some form of login. So, there are two options:

1. In case, SharePoint has REST API you should be able to access your files with the KNIME [REST Nodes](https://nodepit.com/iu/org.knime.rest) or the [Palladian](https://nodepit.com/iu/ws.palladian.nodes) nodes. Uploading should also be possible this way. Check your SharePoint’s REST API documentation about the appropriate endpoints, interfaces, formats, and authentication mechanism.
2. Alternatively, you can “script” your web browser and automate the action which you would do as a user through a KNIME workflow. For that approach, you can use the [Selenium Nodes](http://seleniumnodes.com).

Comment: Hi Daniel, I am trying to either download or read an .xls file from corporative SharePoint, it does log into the network but does not read not download the file, when I try with the "Download" node it does bring down an output, but says 403 FORBIDDEN, is like it tries to download a list instead.